# Parcel Bundler: Everything is okay on localhost but The index.html on Dist is showing Error

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs, node-modules, parceljs

I am learning Parcel and trying to bundle a **index.html** connected with **index.js**. Everything is okay on the parcel `localhost:1234` but in the dist folder when I open the **index.html** the app is not working.

**Note: I know that the problem is caused from using import in my index.js**

My **package.json** File -

```
{
  "name": "reddit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

[My index.html code for script connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAKUz.png)

[My all folders list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJJsP.png)

[importing redditapi.js in index.js(check the all folder list image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVSUO.png)

[The error I am getting when I try to use the APP on index.html from dist folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8lRq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed. The import should not include from. It should be import 'index'; Thank you. Everything was fixed after my NPM run build command.